# Stuck with active records on ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

hi ive just started to learn ruby on rails so i might make some little obvious mistakes but theres one thing i cant get around,

my controller action currently passes the variable to my view:

```
class HomepageController < ApplicationController
  def index
  end

  def Value
    @users = User.all
    render "homepage/Value"
  end
end
```

and this is my current view:

```
    <ul class="users">
    <% @users.each do |user| %>
    <%= user.first_name %>

    <% end %>
</ul>
```

this outputs nothing on my view,
if i change the each statement to:

```
<%= @users.each do |user| %>
```

it displays :

```
[#<User id: 1, first_name: "hello", last_name: "world", email: "", password: nil, created_at: "2017-08-31 10:33:01", updated_at: "2017-08-31 10:33:01">, #<User id: 2, first_name: nil, last_name: "anewworld", email: "emailnew", password: "123", created_at: "2017-08-31 12:35:41", updated_at: "2017-08-31 12:35:41">]
```

i have absolutely no clue why  `<%= user.first_name %>` wouldnt work

Comment: Wrap your `user.first_name` in <li></li> tag, maybe incorrect markup influences to your html.

Comment: Alex can you add more controller code ?

Comment: Check if by mistake you didn't redifine the method first_name inside your User model

Comment: added more controller code

Comment: Can you post the `app/models/user.rb` as well?

Comment: try user.created_at instead of user.first_name. since second user have first_name nil

Comment: instead of doing `<%= user.first_name %>` try using `user.inspect`, it will display a detailed version (as string) of each `user` (if exists).

Answer (score 0):

```
 <ul class="users">
    <% if @users %>
      <% @users.each do |user| %>
        <li>
         <%= user.first_name %>
        </li>
    <%else%>
      <li> No Users </li>
    <%end%>
</ul>
```

"li" tag missing

Comment: same result,just 2 dots on the screen from <li>

Comment: @users = User.all is returning 0 result then

Comment: @users = User.all gives #<User::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x894d9b0>

Comment: @AlexPennings `User.all` will always return an ActiveRecord::Relation object. It acts like an array, it may contain records, or not. To make sure you have existing User records, simply count them: `User.all.count`

Comment: Line 2 should be: `<% if @users.present? %>`